# Manage same Project with different package name in GIT

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I have a project lets say **Project A**( Main Project/ Master). I need to create same projects but with *same code* and *different package name* **Project B** and **Project C**.
If the changes are applicable to all then I will make changes in **Project A**, so that if I update **Project B** and **Project C** automatically they should get the changes.
But if any customization came for project level then I need to change in **Project B** only. It should not affect to **Project A** or **C**. Like this how can I handle all three projects using `git`.
Will it work with using branches.? 
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: In svn it can be handled very easily. Git I'm not sure.

Comment: Git won't do anything automatically. You could create one branch for A, one for B and one for C, but after changing A you need to merge that to B and C for the change to be applied to those branches. Not really convinced branches are the right tool for this.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was surprised because every projects will have diff package names.

Comment: see this : https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/how-did-i-set-up-multiple-flavors-for-an-android-app-under-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) in your code, instead of relying on multiple branches in git. This way, a single source code can be generated as multiple applications.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion ...
    buildToolsVersion ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp"
        ...
    }

    // Specify the build dimension and flavors
    flavorDimensions "type"
    productFlavors {
        typeA {
            dimension "type"
            applicationIdSuffix '.typea' // Add this to differentiate the application ID
            versionNameSuffix "-typea" // Add this to differentiate version naming
        }
        typeB {
            dimension "type"
            applicationIdSuffix '.typeb'
        }
        typeC {
            dimension "type"
            applicationIdSuffix '.typec'
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if your classes are in the same package, as long as your application ID differs, you can install multiple version of the app at the same time on your device.

To build each specific app, simply change the chosen variant in Android Studio.

[image]

For specific flavor implementation in your code, you can use BuildConfig.FLAVOR to check which flavor the current application is.

```
when (BuildConfig.FLAVOR) {
    "typeA" -> {
        // Do stuff for typeA app
    }
    "typeB" -> ...
    "typeC" -> ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But it will have a single source code. how cud we handle project level changes means other application should not get reflect with this changes as mentioned in question.

Comment: You can add some conditions on the code by checking the app flavor at runtime. I just edited the answer